# Избавиться от окна консоли при запуске .exe файла python

Tags: python, консоль, exe

Есть у меня программа написанная на python, при запуске скомпилированного в **.exe** файла, выводится на экран окно консоли. Мне каким-то образом нужно сделать так, чтобы этого окна не было или оно было скрыто.

Пробовал `pyinstaller -F -w main.py` - не работает, пишет `Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your platform.`. Сам bootloader установил, ничего не поменялось.

Формат файла **.pyw** не подходит, так как для него нужен установленный python на компьютере.

Через **py2exe** тоже ничего не получилось. Консоль в любом случае появляется.

Comment: Используйте `pyinstaller ... --windowed ...`

Comment: Файл не создался `Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform.` Платформа - Windows 10.

Comment: Какая архитектура 64 или 32?

Comment: Архитектура 64.

Comment: `Путь к паке python\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\` Какие папки есть по этому пути?

Comment: Там лежат папки **images** и **Windows-64bit-intel**, в **images** 2 картинки типа .ico, в **Windows-64bit-intel** 3 exe файла - run, run_d, runw_d.

Comment: Там ещё должен лежать runw.exe переустановите pyinstaller должно наверное помочь.

Comment: Всё сработало, файл появился, --windowed создало нужный exe файл. Спасибо! Хотите написать ответ для других или это сделаю я?

Comment: Пишите вы мне лень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения проблемы нужно было просто переустановить pyinstaller:
В консоли пишу `pip uninstall pyinstaller`, затем `pip install pyinstaller`.
Теперь для преобразования файла перехожу в директорию нужного .py файла и пишу `pyinstaller -F --windowed file.py`. На выходе получаю .exe файл, при запуске которого не появляется окно консоли, а программа работает в фоне.